# Python: IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python

Been pulling what hair I have left over this :-(

```
if tIn.find("play again") != -1:
      tn.write("yes\n")
      print tn.read_until("WordsWeNeverSee",1.0)  
      tn.write("O\n")
```

I get the error

```
root@kali:~# ./TTT.py
  File "./TTT.py", line 79
    print tn.read_until("WordsWeNeverSee",1.0)  
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your script?

Comment: copy/paste the code from your answer into your interpreter. You most likely have some weird spaces or tabs. Besides, you should indent by 4 spaces, not 6 like here

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the problem is from what you posted.  You need to be very precise about your indentation, and in particular, you should avoid hard tabs, which can cause a lot of problems.  Check for that, and make sure everything lines up properly.  That should fix the problem.

Comment: It is possible to tell what the problem is from what you posted. Checking the source I can see you are mixing tabs and spaces. Best is to use the same style of indentation throughout your code; the very best is to keep your hands away from the Tab key at all times because *spaces* are 'visible' but tabs are not.

Comment: If you're using an IDE or extended text editor of sorts, there's most likely a "Convert all tabs to spaces"-option (I know Sublime Text has that feature)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're mixing tab and spaces in your code. I can see it when I try to edit your question.

Check your code with your text editor.